# Select items where count in another field matches (not updatable)

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here I am trying to get the record for my products where the # swab location in Main table matches the count of swab locations in swab Table and Users can checked off the Y/N to verify that the description of the locations are correct.

Here is the example of my 2 tables.

```
tblMainEquipment
Asset_ID   EquipmentName Num_SwapLocations Verified
234        Saijimon      2                 N
235        Pasquale      3                 N

tblMainSwapLocations
Asset_ID   Swap_location 
234        Particle Cannon
234        RailGun
235        Particle Cannon
```

I use the following query to count the number of records, i avoided using a having query to combine both tables since it is not updatable.

```
qryMainSwapLocationCount    
SELECT MSL.Asset_ID, Count(Asset_ID) AS [Count]
FROM tblMainSwapLocation AS MSL
GROUP BY MSL.Asset_ID;
```

This will give me the result of

```
qryMainSwapLocationCount
Asset_ID   count
234        2
234        1
```

I used the following as a record source for my form to allow users to verify the inputs.

```
SELECT MEQ.Asset_ID, MEQ.Equipment_Name,MEQ.Num_swapLocations MEQ.Verified
FROM tblMainEquipment AS MEQ, qryMainSwapLocationCount AS MSLC
WHERE (((MEQ.Asset_ID)=[MSLC].[Asset_ID]) AND ((MEQ.Num_SwapLocations)=[MSLC].[Count]);
```

This result would be

```
tblMainEquipment
Asset_ID   EquipmentName Num_SwapLocations Verified
234        Saijimon      2                 N
```

However this record set is not editable. Is there any reasons for this?

Comment: Does the query you used for your form's record source actually work in a query?

Comment: I only ask because after you tidy up the first line to `SELECT MEQ.Asset_ID, MEQ.EquipmentName, MEQ.Num_swapLocations, MEQ.Verified` the WHERE clause doesn't seem to work at all. Also you're listing 2 tables in your FROM clause without any kind of join... was that intentional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should put your table **tblMainEquipment** as your recordsource and bring all the fields from that on to your form:

[image]

Then insert an unbound textbox (perhaps close to your **Num_SwapLocations** field for easy comparison):

[image]

Then in this new textbox, put the following in the ControlSource:

`=DCount("ASSET_ID","tblMainSwapLocations","ASSET_ID=" & [Asset_ID])`

[image]

Then open your form and it should count the number of records in table **tblMainSwapLocations** that have the same **Asset_ID** as the record currently showing:

[image]

You'll then be able to update the **Verified** field in your **tblMainEquipment** table.

Comment: yes. I realised that since i will have a joining on the swap location no matter what i do. I decided to create a temporary table as a record source and then update my actual table after changes have been made.

Comment: Oh hang on, I think I see what you're trying to do now... will update my answer...

Comment: that cool. i forgot about using Dcount for this! Is there any way to prevent users from changing the verified field if both the num_swaplocations and swaplocationscount do not match? I am using a continuous form for this

Comment: i Managed to solve the issue for the continuous form by using extra textboxes to enable "tick marks" and locking them if they do not match

Comment: Good stuff. I was going to suggest writing some VBA on the form's BeforeUpdate event, but if you've managed to get what you need then great! :)